# Testing Activity Compensate with MassTransit

Tags: testing, masstransit

I'm trying to test the compensation logic in my Activity, but I can't figure out how to kick off the `Compensate` method in a test. I have an activity that should throw an exception if something isn't found in the DB. I've figured out how to ensure that the activity in faulted in this case, but I can't figure out the compensation part.

My test class is below. Note that awaiting on the `RoutingSlipActivityCompensated` handler throws a `TaskCanceledException`. How do I test the compensation part of the activity?

```
[TestClass]
public class DisableTeamCheckInsActivityTests
{
   Mock<ILogger<DisableTeamCheckInsActivity>> _logger;
   CheckInsDbContext _db;

   InMemoryTestHarness _harness;
   ActivityTestHarness<DisableTeamCheckInsActivity, DisableTeamCheckIns, DisableTeamCheckInsLog> _activity;

   [TestInitialize]
   public async Task Initialize()
   {
      _logger = new Mock<ILogger<DisableTeamCheckInsActivity>>();
      _db = CheckInDbContextFactory.Create();

      _harness = new InMemoryTestHarness
      {
         TestTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
      };

      _activity = _harness.Activity<DisableTeamCheckInsActivity, DisableTeamCheckIns, DisableTeamCheckInsLog>(
         _ => new DisableTeamCheckInsActivity(_logger.Object, _db),
         _ => new DisableTeamCheckInsActivity(_logger.Object, _db)
      );

      await _db.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
      await _harness.Start();
   }

   [TestCleanup]
   public async Task Cleanup()
   {
      await _db.Database.EnsureDeletedAsync();
      await _harness.Stop();
   }

   [TestMethod]
   public async Task Missing_Team_Throws()
   {
      var teamId = Guid.NewGuid();

      var builder = new RoutingSlipBuilder(Guid.NewGuid());
      builder.AddSubscription(_harness.BusAddress, RoutingSlipEvents.All);

      var faulted = _harness.SubscribeHandler<RoutingSlipActivityFaulted>();
      var compensated = _harness.SubscribeHandler<RoutingSlipActivityCompensated>();

      builder.AddActivity(_activity.Name, _activity.ExecuteAddress, new
      {
         TeamId = teamId
      });

      await _harness.Bus.Execute(builder.Build());

      var faultContext = await faulted;
      Assert.AreEqual("System.InvalidOperationException", faultContext?.Message?.ExceptionInfo?.ExceptionType);

      await compensated; // <-- This throws a TaskCanceledException
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A routing slip with a single activity will never compensate. If the activity faults, the routing slip faults, but there isn't any compensation information in the routing slip because there were not any previous activities.

If the activity completed, and a subsequent activity faulted, then the compensate method would be called, and the ActivityCompensated event would be published.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Would you suggest then that I add a "dummy" activity to the end of this test routing slip that faults, so the compensation logic I want is called?

Comment: yes, that's how I test compensation in the Courier unit tests.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, I'll add for anyone in the future looking at this that it's important to use transactions in your activity in case you ever end up being the one activity in a routing slip. Since the activity is never compensated if it's the only one in a routing slip, you don't want to leave any state partially modified that won't be rolled back.